# C# Empty array not accepting input

Tags: c#, arrays, textbox

What I'm attempting to do is enter data into the empty arrays using a form textbox.  The form will display the first array(values are already entered), but it will not accept the values that entering into the textbox.  No matter what value I enter, it posts $0.00 in the whole row.  It won't even take in a name(string).  Can anyone guide me in the right direction.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WP_Week3_Part1
{
    public partial class ArrayForm : Form
    {
        int[] deptArray = new int[5] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
        double[] contArray = new double[5] { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};
        string[] nameArray = new string[5] { "", "", "", "", "" };
        public ArrayForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void buttonValue_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int dept;
            dept = Convert.ToInt32(textBoxDept.Text);
            double cont;
            cont = Convert.ToDouble(textBoxCont.Text);
            textBoxDept.Text = "";
            textBoxCont.Text = "";
            textBoxDonor.Text = "";
            labelOutput.Text = "Printing Contribution Table \n dept          amount          donor";
            for (int i = 0; i < deptArray.Length; i = i + 1)
            {
                nameArray[i] = textBoxDonor.Text;
                labelOutput.Text += String.Format("\n {0}          {1}          {2} ", deptArray[i], contArray[i].ToString("C"), nameArray[i]);
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: 1- You clear `textBoxDonor.Text` before assign to the array. 2-You dont add nothing to `contArray` nor `deptArray` 3- You will overwrite all the `nameArray` each time you press the button.

Comment: Are you taking the input from the TextBox on buttonValue_Click? If so, you are resetting the .Text property to an empty string.. so of course it will be 0.

Answer (score 1):

You have two problems:

1. You get the `cont` value and then *do nothing with it*. You print `contArray[i]` but that is not assigned after being initialized to 0, so of course it always prints 0. Not sure what the logic is *supposed* to be based on your code, but either print `cont` or assign the array member(s).
2. You clear the donor text box (`textBoxDoneor.Text = ""`) before using it in the `for` loop. So when you assign the element of `nameArray`, you are always assigning the empty string. You also always assign every member of the array, not sure if that is intentional or you just haven't gotten that far with your program yet.

Comment: 1.  where am I initializing con to 0?

Comment: so setting the three textBox.Text = "" is clearing them?

Comment: @Bob you are setting it to 0 in the contArray initialization, and yes setting it to "" clears it.

Answer (score 1):

It returns `$0.00` because:

You set your text `textBoxDonor` to empty

it should be like this:

```
            int dept;
            dept = Convert.ToInt32(textBoxDept.Text);
            double cont;
            cont = Convert.ToDouble(textBoxCont.Text);
            //textBoxDept.Text = "";
            //textBoxCont.Text = "";
            //textBoxDonor.Text = "";
            labelOutput.Text = "Printing Contribution Table \n dept          amount          donor";
            for (int i = 0; i < deptArray.Length; i = i + 1)
            {
                nameArray[i] = textBoxDonor.Text;
                labelOutput.Text += String.Format("\n {0}          {1}          {2} ", deptArray[i], contArray[i].ToString("C"), nameArray[i]);


     }
```

Checking the content of your `nameArray` right after the execution

```
        string arrlist = string.Empty;
        foreach (var arr in nameArray.ToList())
        { 
           arrlist = arrlist +' ' + arr.ToString();
        }
        MessageBox.Show(arrlist);
```

Comment: I fixed what everyone seems to be suggesting, but now whatever i enter i.e. 10.00 and Bob fills every row.

Comment: Yeah it absolutely fills every row because your `nameArray` just depend on the content of your` textBoxDonor`.. My Question is what you are trying to do exactly to that nameArray?`.